# Primeng schedule with Angular2 webpack

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, webpack, primeng

I'm going to use Primeng schedule (http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule) within a project based on Angular2 webpack starter(https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter).

Since Primeng schedule depends on `fullcalendar.js` which is a jQuery plugin, I try to load `fullcalendar` and jQuery through webpack. I follow example at here (https://github.com/cagataycivici/angular2-webpack-starter).

In `package.json`, I added settings below to `"devDependencies"`

```
"fullcalendar": "^2.7.2",
"jquery": "^2.2.4",
"jquery-ui": "^1.10.5",
```

and added settings below to `vendor.js`

```
import 'script!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';
import 'script!moment/moment.js';
import 'script!fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js';
```

But the problem is that the Primeng schedule is not rendered in the webpage, even though the `<p-schedule></p-schedule>` tag is actually there. Did I miss something?

Comment: Never mind. It turns out to be my mistake. After adding `Schedule` to the corresponding component's directive field, it appears. And, adding `{
           from: 'node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css',
           to: 'assets/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css'
       }` to `CopyWebpackPlugin` applies the css.

Comment: Hey do you mind sharing some important parts of your application with me im also trying to get the schedule working on a webpack angular 2 seed but for the life of me I cant get it working. Just the parts related to ngprime and the schedule component? Would appreciate it VERY much

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the **angular-cli.json**, add these to the **angular-cli.json** file

```
"styles"           : [
                "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css",
                "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
                "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css"
            ],
            "scripts"          : [
                "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
                "../node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
                "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js"
            ],
```