# PrimeNG Schedule on WebPack Angular 2

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, webpack, primeng

Is there anybody out there that has gotten the PrimeNG schedule to work a webpack angular 2 app? Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447536/primeng-schedule-with-angular2-webpack) oak I couldnt get it working, unlike him I still cant.

In my vendor.ts i load the required libs:

```
require('script!../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js');
require('script!../node_modules/moment/moment.js');
require('script!../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js');
```

In my component i import the schedule from primeng

```
import {Schedule} from 'primeng/components/schedule/schedule';
```

and add the directive

```
 directives : [Schedule]
```

and in my view

```
<p-schedule [events]="events"></p-schedule>
```

It tunes me that this.schedule.fullCalendar is not a function. in the schedule.js.

PS: Before i tried to insert the schedule i inserted a button just to check if my Prime is hooked up properly, it looked 100%

If anybody can help me please, im at my wits end

Thanks

Comment: did you found the cause of error - having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Then found out I had `import 'script!jquery';` later in my code overwriting the fullcalendar plugin. Once I removed the second import/require it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the other day that in the primeng setup page they actually detail a starter webpack project now. I think its pretty new, i havent gotten around to trying it yet, but sure it will solve these problems